# How to extend/modify (customize) Bootstrap with SASS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, sass, bootstrap-5

I want to create a website theme based on Bootstrap. I want to extend Bootstrap's default components and change some of them. For this, I would need *access* to SASS variables that Bootstrap defines so I can override them.

I though of cloning Bootstrap from GitHub and changing it directly, but I heard that's actually not good practice. Could you give me some advice please?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

**Update 2022 (Bootstrap 5)**

Generally speaking, customizing Bootstrap 5 SASS works the same way as it did in Bootstrap 4. However, some of the maps have changed (and new ones have been added) so you should [follow the Bootstrap SASS documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/customize/sass/) for details on how to add, remove or modify any of the maps.

Recent comments on this post indicate there's still some confusion about the order of customizations and imports. However, this concept hasn't changed...

> **"Variable overrides must come after our functions are imported, but before the rest of the imports"**

Because of the way SASS variable defaults work, bootstrap ("the rest of the imports") should be imported **AFTER** any variable customizations/changes. Since your variable changes will not contain the `!default` flag, your changes will not be overridden by the Bootstrap defaults when bootstrap is imported at the end.

[The proof is in the pudding](https://codeply.com/p/zp0gRtfPsi)

---

**Here's how to override / customize Bootstrap 4** with SASS...

Overrides and customizations should be kept in a separate `custom.scss` file that is separate from the Bootstrap SASS source files. This way any changes you make don't impact the Bootstrap source, which makes changes or upgrading Bootstrap later much easier.

1- Consider Bootstrap's SASS folder structure, alongside your `custom.scss`...

```
|-- \bootstrap
|   |-- \scss
|   |   |-- \mixins
|   |   |-- \utilities
|   |   |-- bootstrap.scss
|   |   |-- variables.scss
|   |   |-- functions.scss
|   |   |-- ...more bootstrap scss files
|   custom.scss
```

2- In your `custom.scss`, [import the Bootstrap files](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#importing) that are needed for the overrides. (*Usually*, this is just **`variables.scss`**. In some cases, with more complex cutomizations, you may also need the `functions`, `mixins`, and other Bootstrap files.). Make the changes, then `@import "bootstrap"`. **It's important to import Bootstrap *after* the changes...**

```
/* custom.scss */    

/* import the necessary Bootstrap files */
@import "bootstrap/functions";
@import "bootstrap/variables";

/* make changes to the !default Bootstrap variables */    
$body-color: green;
        
/* finally, import Bootstrap to set the changes! */
@import "bootstrap";
```

2a (*optional*) - Also, you can *extend existing Bootstrap classes* *after* the `@import "bootstrap";` to create new *custom* classes. For example, here is a new `.row-dark` class that extends (inherits from) the Bootstrap `.row` class and then add a background-color.

```
 /* create new custom classes from existing classes */
 .row-dark {
    @extend .row;
    background-color: #333333;
    color: #ffffff;
 }
```

3- Compile the SASS (node-sass, gulp-sass, webpack/NPM, etc..). The CSS output will contain the overrides! Don't forget to check the includePaths if your @imports fail. For a **full list of variables** you can override, see the [variables.scss](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_variables.scss) file. There are also these [global variables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#sass-options).

[**Bootstrap SASS Demo on Codeply**](https://codeply.com/go/ZIRPuQ7E3x)

**In summary, here's how it works:**

1_ First, when the `custom.scss` file is processed using SASS, the !default values are defined in the `bootstrap/variables.scss`.

2_ Next, our custom values are set, which will override any of the variables that had !default values set in `bootstrap/variables.scss`.

3_ Finally, Bootstrap is imported (`@import "bootstrap"`) which enables the SASS processor (A.K.A. compiler) to generate all the appropriate CSS using both the Bootstrap defaults and the custom overrides.

For those that don't know SASS, try this [tool](https://themestr.app/) that I made.

---

Also see:
[How to get 15 columns in Bootstrap 4 in SASS CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41513247/how-to-get-15-columns-in-bootstrap-4-in-sass-css/41514227)
[Bootstrap v4 grid sizes / Sass List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39546031/bootstrap-v4-grid-sizes-sass-list/39546573#39546573)
[Customizing Bootstrap CSS template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596794/customizing-bootstrap-css-template)
[Extending Bootstrap 4 and SASS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49755065/extending-bootstrap-4-and-sass/49755426#49755426)

Comment: How do you approach avoiding writing BS classes in HTML? Say I want only custom classes: ```.title``` for example could be written in SCSS as ```.title {
    @extend .display-3;
    @extend .text-primary;
  } ```

But ```@extend``` is supposed to be cursed https://www.sitepoint.com/avoid-sass-extend/ so am not sure if this is a good idea? I do not want ANY Bootstrap classes in my HTML.

Comment: What happens if I set `$body-color: green;` without importing the `bootstrap/variables.scss` file before it. It wont work?

Comment: Given the file structure, wouldn't it be : ```@import "bootstrap/scss/functions"; @import "bootstrap/scss/variables"; @import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";``` ?

Comment: @Fritzip No it depends. Those are relative paths so they are relative to however bootstrap is included/installed in your SASS compiler.

Comment: Please see that this is almost correct, but the imports (of things like variables, functions, etc.) must come AFTER the setting of the overrides if using Bootstrap 4.  https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-npm-starter/issues/43

Comment: No, because if you need to reference an existing variable you must import the variables first. What you're saying only works IF you don't need to reference/use another bootstrap variable. This is widely documented as the correct method for both Bootstrap 4 & 5 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/customize/sass/#importing

Comment: This is not a solution because all this does is override the stuff in the bootstrap files. This happens because "@import bootstrap" just reimports the same files over again and overrides it. I do not believe this is the way the utilities API is supposed to work.

Comment: @AndrewBrntt - no, `@import bootstrap` doesn't override any prior overrides/changes .. read how SASS [variable defaults work](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/customize/sass/#variable-defaults). When you remove the !default flag in your customizations the variable gets set and subsequent !default flags (as set in bootstrap) will not override the changes., "Variable overrides must come after our functions are imported, but *before* the rest of the imports."

Comment: `@extend` comes with major performance implications and shouldn't be used

Answer (score 5):

I will explain from scratch: Download Ruby because sass is written in Ruby. Open the “start command prompt with Ruby” and enter this:

```
gem install sass
```

In macos, ruby is already installed. so in terminal:

```
sudo gem install sass
```

If you did install bootstrap through package manager; write this code into main.scss

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

then navigate to your work directory where you keep your main.scss or main.css files. Enter this code into command line:

```
sass main.scss main.css
```

this will initialize compiling sass to css.

If you did download bootstrap source files, find the “scss” folder in your source folder

```
BOOTSTRAP\bootstrap-4.2.1\bootstrap-4.2.1\scss
```

and copy it into your style folder in your project where u keep all styling files:css,scss,bootstrap then import “bootstrap.scss” file into main.scss

```
@import "./scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

And now initialize compiling by entering this code:

```
sass main.scss main.css
```

Finally, you can type:

```
sass --watch main.scss:main.css //this should be running
```

to watch all changes in main.css DONT FORGET: You will write your css codes into main.scss, sass will compile it to main.css and you will LINK main.css file in your html.

If you are using visual studio code, you can install “Live Sass Compiler” extension and down below you will see “Watch Sass” button. create main.scss file in the style folder and after import the files the way I explained above, click on the “watch Sass” button and it will start compiling.

Now in bootstrap folder, under scss folder there is `_variables.scss` folder. this contains bootstrap variables. let's say you wanna change border-radius.  in `main.scss` file, before importing your bootstrap:

```
$border-radius:10rem
@import "./scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

Answer (score 2):

It took me a bit to piece together an adequate tutorial to install and use sass with homebrew to edit bootstrap 4 in a node/express project.

Install sass using homebrew

```
brew install sass/sass/sass
```

Install bootstrap in your project

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```

Change to assets dir, create sass directory, create app and custom file

```
cd public/assets/css && mkdir sass && touch sass/app.scss sass/custom.scss
```

In app.scss add the following

```css
// import bootstrap files
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
// import bootstrap defaults
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
// import customization
@import "custom.scss";
// finally, import Bootstrap to set the changes!
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

In custom.scss add a sample customization

```css
$hotness: #fb3f7c;
$link-color: $hotness;
```

Run sass; automatically export/update .css file

```
sass --watch sass/app.scss sass/bootstrap.css
```

Link to the new bootstrap file in your html

References

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/
- https://sass-lang.com/install

Answer (score 1):

Github version of Bootstrap always changes since the foundation itself is being updated constantly. Not to mention, the way Bootstrap is structured, it doesn't necessarily compile the way your SASS compiler will export. The best practice is to structure it the way best suitable for you.

Here's how I usually structure my entire project

```
/style/
/style/theme.scss
/style/theme.min.css
/style/bootstrap.scss
/style/bootstrap.min.css
/style/bootstrap/{subfiles}
/style/bootstrap/mixins/{subfiles}
/style/bootstrap/utilities/{subfiles}

/scripts/
/scripts/bootstrap.min.js
/scripts/main.min.js
/scripts/bootstrap/
```

This assumes you have sass and js minifier.

Answer (score 0):

First of all install **SASS**, you can check which one fits you the most in  https://sass-lang.com/install/
Then **SASS** will help you to compile your scss files to css files.

To watch compiled files type to cli ***sass --watch input.scss output.css***

To compile scss file and add to css file type to cli  ***sass input.scss:output.css***

or compile scss file and add to css file and exclude .map files that are added type to cli ***sass input.scss:output.css --no-source-map***

You will need ***bootstrap-scss*** files, if you using node then when downloaded ***bootstrap*** through *npm*, this folder should exist in your node modules, but if you downloaded and attached for example *bootstrap.min.css* then you will need to download this folder seperately. You can find it here:https://github.com/crissdev/bootstrap-scss

Do not override files in ***bootstrap-scss*** package, it is not the best practice. If letter on you will update the version, then all your customization will be lost and it is very hard to maintain it.

My Folders/ Files tree of bootstrap in app after downloads:

```
extras- 
    bootstrap-
           bootstrap-scss
           bootstrap.bundle.min.js
           bootstrap.min.css       
    
    scss-
           custom.scss
```

In html file, for instance index.html only add: *bootstrap.min.css* , *index.css* and  *bootstrap.bundle.min.js*  files for bootstrap to work. Do not include *custom.scss* file or *bootstrap-scss* folder.

For my scss to be applied I had to play a little bit with imports in *custom.scss* file.
A structure of imports is very *important*, I have followed the import structure from my downloaded ***bootstrap/bootstrap-scss/bootstrap*** file that imports *everything*. I have added all imports from that file and deleted the ones that was not needed (my scss was applied without them).
If you want to add all imports then just add properties or variables that you want to change/update and below them import ***bootstrap/bootstrap-scss/bootstrap*** file. For instance:

```
    $body-color: #121dea;
    $primary: orange;
    #nav {
        position: sticky;
        top:0px;    
     }
    @import "../bootstrap/bootstrap-scss/bootstrap";
```

Or you could import just the ones that you need. For instance I had to add all these imports in order to be able to see that my scss
was applied.

```
    // /functions must be applied first before updating or changing properties/variables etc...
    @import "../bootstrap/bootstrap-scss/functions";
    
    $body-color: #121dea;
    $primary: orange;
    #nav {
        position: sticky;
        top:0px;    
        
    }
    @import "../bootstrap/bootstrap-scss/variables";
    //doesnt have to have var dark if not used
    //@import "../bootstrap/bootstrap-scss/variables-dark";
    @import "../bootstrap/bootstrap-scss/maps";
    @import "../bootstrap/bootstrap-scss/mixins";
    @import "../bootstrap/bootstrap-scss/utilities";
    @import "../bootstrap/bootstrap-scss/root";
    @import "../bootstrap/bootstrap-scss/reboot";
    //if wanted to add any more imports, they must be applied after /reboot and before /utilities/api, at least in my case.
    // For instance /nav import must be here if in use... 
    //@import "../bootstrap/bootstrap-scss/nav";
    @import "../bootstrap/bootstrap-scss/utilities/api";
```

Have a look at the official site for more info about how to change, update variables, properties etc... they are explaining it well in here : [https://sass-lang.com/guide/](https://%20%20%20%20%20https://sass-lang.com/guide/)

Also a specificity is very important when want to override your css. For example lets say you had a *nav* element with a *position:static* in bootstrap files and wanted to change it to *sticky*, then you might need to add in scss file that element more specificly, perhaps

```
div .div-class nav .navbar {
    position:sticky; 
    top: 0px
}
```

or you might add an id to that element, to be able to get better specificity

```
#nav-id {
   position:sticky;
   top: 0px
}
```

I hope it will help someone.