# Bootstrap Customization SASS Variables Override Not Working

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4

Trying to customize Bootstrap as documented here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/options/

Here's my `main.scss` file:

```
@charset 'utf-8';

@import 'variables';
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:500,700');
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css');
@import 'layouts';
```

In the variables files, I have:

```
$font-family-base: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
$body-color: red;
```

However, these variables are ignored by Bootstrap. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But you are importing the css file.

Just download the sass source, import it and then you can edit bootstrap variables.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the **bootstrap/ scss** *after* any variables that are changed to override the default variables..

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:500,700');

$font-family-base: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; 
$body-color: red;

@import 'bootstrap';
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/ZIRPuQ7E3x

Also see: [How to extend/modify (customize) Bootstrap 4 with SASS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776055/how-to-extend-modify-customize-bootstrap-4-with-sass/49070142#49070142)