# Overriding an scss variable by referencing other variable

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4

Technically this isn't a boostrap thing, it's a scss thing, but Bootstrap is the context of which I am having issues.  I am changing the default value of some values in bootstrap.  One particular variable, I want to reference another bootstrap variable.

So I have my own file:

```
@import "_variable.overrides.scss";
@import "bootstrap.scss";
```

my _variable.overrides.scss looks like this:

```
$secondary: lighten($primary, 10%);
```

I can't do that because $primary is undefined since I am importing my overrides scss first.  If I import boostrap.scss first, it doesn't override, because overrides have to come before the default variable definition.

Is there any way to override one variable by referencing another variable?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this has been answered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45807835/bootstrap-customization-sass-variables-override-not-working) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776055/how-to-extend-modify-customize-bootstrap-4-with-sass). You need to *first* @import any variables you want to reference in your custom SCSS..

Since `$primary` lives in _variables.scss, you need to @import `_variables.scss` and `_functions.scss` (since this is ref'd by _variables.scss):

```
@import "bootstrap/functions";
@import "bootstrap/variables";
```

Then, as [explained in the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/theming/#variable-defaults), your custom vars will override Bootstrap's because all the Bootstrap variables use the `!default` flag, which means they won't take precedence over your custom vars which are imported *before* Bootstrap. So the entire SCSS would look like (you may need to edit the paths):

```
@import "bootstrap/functions";
@import "bootstrap/variables";
@import "_variable.overrides.scss";
@import "bootstrap.scss";
```