# Customize Bootstrap 4's grid-system Breakpoints

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I have an application where the design needs a 1280 breakpoint from desktop to tablet, or, xl to lg respectively. However, Bootstrap itself has the xl breakpoint at 1200.

I need to change that xl breakpoint globally for bootstrap. Do I have to recompile Bootstrap 4 from the source files?

I tried setting this in with my Sass build:

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  // Extra small screen / phone
  xs: 0,
  // Small screen / phone
  sm: 576px,
  // Medium screen / tablet
  md: 768px,
  // Large screen / desktop
  lg: 992px,
  // Extra large screen / wide desktop
  xl: 1280px
);

$container-max-widths: (
  sm: 540px,
  md: 720px,
  lg: 960px,
  xl: 1220px
);
```

However, nothing changed with the breakpoint for xl globally, it still would do the break instead at 1200px wide.

Comment: Note: Most of the answers here use breakpoints that are supposedly incompatible with Bootstrap. There are some [mathematical requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54027304/114558).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

### Bootstrap 4.x & 5.x

You need to override the `$grid-breakpoints` **and** `$container-max-widths` variables BEFORE importing the Bootstrap sources. Here a working example (***scss***):

```css
// File: theme.scss
// Override default BT variables:
$grid-breakpoints: (
        xs: 0,
        sm: 576px,
        md: 768px,
        lg: 992px,
        xl: 1200px,
        xxl: 1900px
);
    
$container-max-widths: (
        sm: 540px,
        md: 720px,
        lg: 960px,
        xl: 1140px,
        xxl: 1610px
);
    
// Import BT sources
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

// Your CSS (SASS) rules here...
```

Comment: I read the bootstrap documentation, but there is no xxl size. This is only given by a third party. Are you using this? https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-xxl

Comment: @TitoLeiva No, I have simply defined a custom new width for my use case. You can define whatever you want.

Answer (score 34):

Changing the `$grid-breakpoints` variable will work fine. Remember that you must import `/bootstrap` or the `bootstrap/variables` in the `custom.scss`, and then @import bootstrap *after.*

For example:

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 600px,
  md: 800px,
  lg: 1000px,
  xl: 1280px
);
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/go/MlIRhbJYGj

Also see: [How to extend/modify (customize) Bootstrap 4 with SASS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776055/how-to-extend-modify-customize-bootstrap-4-with-sass/49070142#49070142)

Comment: I'm pretty sure we also have to update `$container-max-widths`, right?

Answer (score 12):

According to their [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#variable-defaults), in order to customize Bootstrap you need to:

1. copy/paste from `/scss/_variables.scss` to `_custom.scss` whatever you want to modify
2. remove any `!default` from the pasted code and change the values to what you want
3. recompile (see [Build tools](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/build-tools/)) - you need to successfully run `npm run dist` to rebuild from source.

You're not supposed to modify anything inside `_variables.scss` as you will lose those changes upon upgrading Bootstrap. With the steps above, you can safely upgrade Bootstrap and keep your mods.

**Note:** Even if you don't care about upgrading, and you want to modify directly in `/scss/_variables.scss`, you still need to recompile to apply the changes to your `/dist/` files.

---

Addendum: to address basZero's concern about this not being a "recommended solution", I'd argue Bootstrap has been built from the ground up to be modular and configurable. They provide ample documentation:

- [build tools](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/build-tools/)
- [theming](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/theming/)
- as well as a map to its [contents](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/contents/)

If recompilation wasn't recommended, I'd argue they wouldn't have gone through the trouble of documenting it in such detail.

Another useful tool is [bootstrap.build](https://bootstrap.build/) which is basically an online recompilation tool (and it's not the only one).

Through compilation you can change the number of columns, or the margin/padding utility spacer values, responsiveness breakpoints and, most importantly, you can specify which modules to include: one could limit bootstrap to its grid system only or the buttons module or could choose to only include its modals.

Comment: that's not a recommended solution, you shouldn't modify bootstrap definition files. Rather override them in your own SCSS before importing the bootstrap SCSS.

Comment: @basZero, I've added to my answer to address your concern.

Comment: i'm sorry, I must have misunderstood your solution. Now it's clear and correct!