# Set Bootstrap container class to 940px max

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 with the container at default width on my desktop screen.

I want the main content section of my app to be max 940px container on big screen.

Do I simply override the bootstrap container class, or create new class container-2? or something else?

Edit

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 4 Change Breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47747208/bootstrap-4-change-breakpoints)

Comment: @DestinatioN in this case its nothing about breakpoints. He only wants the container to be smaller.

Comment: @J.Sadi yes correct, thanks

Comment: Yes, but the container size and breakpoints are related to each other and should be changed by modifying the `$grid-breakpoints` and `$container-max-widths` variable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

according to the bootstrap.css you could build your own container class. These are the classes you have to 'rebuild':

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 540px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 720px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 960px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1140px;
  }
}

.container {
  min-width: 992px !important;
}
```

You should never override original bootsrap-classes.

---

To ensure that everything works well you could do something like this:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container.max-width-940 {
    max-width: 940px !important;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container.max-width-940 {
    max-width: 940px !important;
  }
}

.container.max-width-940 {
  min-width: 940px !important;
}
```

and use it like: `<div class="container max-width-940"></div>`

Comment: Ill try this for now I think.

Comment: forgot to say, that you have to keep using the container-class to ensure, that everything is working like it does before. Take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Added the 3 classes to the style.css, and changed "container" to "container max-width-940" and hasn't made container smaller. Added screen cap of chrome inspector to OP,.

Comment: My fault.. just remove the spaces between `.container` and `.max-width-940` like `.container.max-width-940`. Edited my answer. And here is a [working example](https://www.bootply.com/3zl47dD4rn)

Answer (score 1):

Since the Bootstrap container is responsive and uses media queries to set the max-width.

**The container alone is only used to define width, auto margins and padding.** Other grid class (ie row, col) are *not* dependent on it, so it would be easiest to define your own custom container.

To define your own `container-940`...

```
.container-940 {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 940px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/QOAjmGLp7K

**Or,** if you want to use the existing `.container` the overrides would be...

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 940px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 940px;
  }
}
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/QOAjmGLp7K

---

If you want to *change* the max-width to be smaller on smaller widths than you'd adjust the media queries as desired:

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .container {
    max-width: ??px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: ??px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 940px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 940px;
  }
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something very obvious but it depends which reference is first in your code: bootstrap CSS or your personal CSS file. All things equal the last reference wins.