# How to increase the max-width of the container with bootstrap4?

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4, width

I can not increase the maximum width of my container. How to change the width in the source code?

I already tried to change the size of the width in the bootstrap-grid.css page.

The Element Inspector allows me to change the max-width. How to modify the _grid.scss: 6 file?

[image: What I want to change]

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container {
        max-width: 1140px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The browser is showing the SASS maps. If you want to simply **use CSS**, override each container breakpoint...

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .container {
    max-width: ??px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: ??px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    max-width: ??px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: ??px;
  }
}
```

CSS Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/zTBLpNsTDi
SASS Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/5D8PrphU4b

---

Also see: [Set Bootstrap container class to 940px max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53761060/set-bootstrap-container-class-to-940px-max/53761350#53761350)

Or, **using SASS**: [Bootstrap 4 min width fluid container (change responsive behavior)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53856896/bootstrap-4-min-width-fluid-container-change-responsive-behavior/53858353#53858353)