# how to add xxl and xxxl bootstrap breakpoints to react-strap app

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I want to add two extra breakpoints to my react-strap applications for large desktop displays (like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54027024/adding-xxl-xxxl-breakpoints-what-is-container-max-widths)).  I'm using an [airframe](https://github.com/0wczar/airframe-react) template but cannot figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Where ever you keep your variable overrides add your new break points.
Here I've added the xxl breakpoint.

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
        xs: 0,
        sm: 576px,
        md: 768px,
        lg: 992px,
        xl: 1200px,
        xxl: 1700px
);

$container-max-widths: (
        sm: 540px,
        md: 720px,
        lg: 960px,
        xl: 1140px,
        xxl: 1615px
);
```

Then on your components you'll have to use the actual class name

```
<Col className="col-xxl-6" lg="12" xl="8">

</Col>
```

Comment: The same place you put all your other variables.  It's entirely up to you.  Some people create their own variable overrides file.  Some people put them in their main .scss file.