# Add XXXL to Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, sass

I watched this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Ovw43Dkp44) on customising the default Boostrap code and read this post [Adding XXL & XXXL breakpoints. What is container-max-widths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54027024/adding-xxl-xxxl-breakpoints-what-is-container-max-widths).

Unfortunately I can not get Google Chrome or Firefox to recognise XXL or XXXL.

[image]

**main.scss**
[image]

```
  $grid-breakpoints: (
    xs: 0,
    sm: 576px,
    md: 768px,
    lg: 992px,
    xl: 1200px,
    xxl: 1440px,
    xxxl: 1600px
  );

$container-max-widths: (
    sm: 540px,
    md: 720px,
    lg: 960px,
    xl: 1140px,
    xxl: 1380px,
    xxxl: 1560px
);

@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

**main.css**

main.css is 9438 lines long so I have pasted it here - https://codeshare.io/lovOdm.

Answer (score 0):

As we imported all the Bootstrap CSS code into main.css, we no longer needed to link to the default Bootstrap CSS Style sheet.

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS - No longer needed -->
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
```

But then after looking at Inspect Elements, I noticed I was linking to the wrong main.css.

I was linking to this one.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "main.css" %}">
```

[image]

Whereas I had just copied the Bootstrap code to this one

[image]

I did not want to interfere with main.css in blog/static so I created a main1.css in blog/static.

In the terminal I  ran `C:\Users\ACER\Documents\Django Projects\EcommerceProject>scss main.scss blog/static/main1.css`

Whereas previously in terminal I was running `C:\Users\ACER\Documents\Django Projects\EcommerceProject>scss main.scss main.css`

And then whenever I wanted to use Bootstrap code I would just reference this Stylesheet

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "main1.css" %}">
```