# Is it possible to set breakpoint in pixels like "@include media-breakpoint-up(900px)" (bootstrap4)?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sass, media-queries

Can I build media query using `@include media-breakpoint-up(900px)` in Bootstrap 4?

For example if I use:

```
@include media-breakpoint-up(900px){
   body: border 2px solid;
}
```

the output in .css will be without media query -> [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDBdx.png)

Or it can be done only with creating of new breakpoint:

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
    // default breakpoints

    custom-lg: 90px,
);
```

and using like

```
@include media-breakpoint-up(custom-lg){
   body: border 2px solid;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to change the `lg` breakpoint?

Comment: I need to specify style for elements on specific width and don`t want to create a new breakpoint for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If look at the `media-breakpoint-up` mixin, you'll see it expects the `$name` parameter, which is the name of a breakpoint, *not* a pixel value..

```
@mixin media-breakpoint-up($name, $breakpoints: $grid-breakpoints) {
    ...
}
```

But you could pass in an alternative $breakpoints map (the 2nd param) with the new value for `lg`...

```
@include media-breakpoint-up(lg,(lg:900px)){
   body { 
       border: solid red 2px;
   }
}
```

[Codeply](https://codeply.com/p/kKcf71ka07)

Related: [Bootstrap 4 Change Breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47747208/bootstrap-4-change-breakpoints/47753600#47753600)

Comment: Thanks, that`s what I was looking for!