# How to launch col-sm bootstrap class at screen size 768px?

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

At the screen size of 768px, the bootstrap class col-md is implemented. Is there a way to change this so that the class col-sm is implemented at this screen size instead?

These are the current defaults:

- Extra Small (<576px) .col-
- Small (>= 576px) .col-sm-
- Medium (>=768px) .col-med-
- Large (>=992px) .col-lg-
- Extra Large (>=1200px) .col-xl-

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47747208/bootstrap-4-change-breakpoints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think this is make sense**

the code:

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .col-sm {
    flex: 0 0 100% !important;
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm {
    flex: 1 0 0% !important;
  }
}
```

but why you want to change the col-sm use col-md instead

Comment: Thanks so much! I had a few components bound to col-md that I didn't want to change at the screen sizes between 768px and 992px.