# Bootstrap 4 release - create custom css

Tags: npm, gruntjs, bootstrap-4

I am trying to figure out how to build a custom css for B4 released version. I have downloaded source files but don't see a `Gruntfile.js` that I used for v4.alpha6. I am looking at:
[V4 doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/)
which says:

> Should you require build tools, they are included for developing Bootstrap and its docs, but they’re likely unsuitable for your own purposes.

So, what do I use for my own purposes? How do I build a custom css? I see that I have to create my own `_custom.scss` file, but I am not sure about the `Gruntfile.js`. I copied the one from alpha6 version, but it's not running. I am getting this:

> ```
> D:\Bootstrap4\bootstrap-4.0.0>grunt
> grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface (v1.2.0)
>
> Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.
> ```

If you're seeing this message, grunt hasn't been installed locally to
your project.

However, the same file runs fine for alpha6 version.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Bootstrap 4 beta, they moved away from Gulp and [over to Webpack](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/), but there are other ways you can generate CSS from SASS.

To create a custom CSS, you need a SASS compiler such as node-sass or Webpack SASS, or gulp SASS to compile the SCSS to CSS. Then change the whatever [SASS variables](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_variables.scss) as needed for the customizations in the `custom.scss` file . The changes should be made before you `@import bootstrap`  in the `custom.scss` file to override the default Bootstrap variables.

If you prefer not to work directly with the SASS variables, or don't want to set-up your own SASS compiler, there are tools available that make the customization process easier. I created [themestr.app](https://themestr.app) which is a custom CSS builder that provides a simple UI to make the changes and generates the `custom.scss` or `custom.css` for download.

**More info:**
[How to extend/modify (customize) Bootstrap 4 with SASS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776055/how-to-extend-modify-customize-bootstrap-4-with-sass/49070142#49070142)
[How to customize Bootstrap 4](https://uxplanet.org/how-to-customize-bootstrap-b8078a011203)

Comment: Any documentation for these other ways, please?

Comment: I elaborated in my answer

Answer (score 1):

As [ZimSystem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171456/zimsystem)  stated, Webpack is the new way forward with Bootstrap.  I found, after hitting the jump, the documentation was a bit lacking.

More digging led me to https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/24370 and the issue author's repo https://github.com/xdvarpunen/webpackboot which has what you need to get going with sass, npm webpack and bootstrap.