# extend bootstrap 4 margin sizing

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4 with sass(`scss file`), and want to apply `.mx-2` class properties into a new class. theorytically some thing like:

```
.MyCustomClass{
  @extend .mx-2;
}
```

But apparently, compiler cannot find `.mx-2` selector and it fails.
I know that `mx-2` class created by using mixture of `$size`, `$length`, `$spacers` ,`$breakpoint` etc... 
So i changed it:

```
.MyCustomClass{
  margin-left: ($spacer * .5) !important;
  margin-right: ($spacer * .5) !important;
}
```

I'm wondering to know:

1. If there is a better, neater way to do that?
2. If i can replace `.5` with some variable?
3. What if i want to extend another sizing class like: `.mx-lg-2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "But apparently, compiler cannot find .mx-2 selector and it fails."

It should work, but you need to `@import "bootstrap"` first. Any `@extend` should be *after* the import...

```
@import "bootstrap";

.MyCustomClass{
  @extend .mx-2;
}
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/UHzJirtyju

---

[How to extend/modify (customize) Bootstrap 4 with SASS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776055/how-to-extend-modify-customize-bootstrap-4-with-sass)