# Error using @include with scss

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4

How do I get media queries to work in bootstrap? I have a SCSS file, I think I need to import something but I have no idea what.

**Error message:**

```
Scss compiler error: Error: no mixin named media-breakpoint-up
```

Path: `homepage.scss`

```
@include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
  h1.home-page {
    font-size: 3rem;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using compiled version (.css) of bootstrap?

Answer (score 3):

You could @import the entire "bootstrap" scss, and then define the custom @include...

```
@import "bootstrap";

@include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
  h1.home-page {
    font-size: 3rem;
  }
}
```

***or,*** you can import functions, variables and mixins (since this includes only what is needed for the mixin)...

```
@import "bootstrap/functions";
@import "bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";

/* change col style on sm only */
@include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
  h1.home-page {
    font-size: 3rem;
  }
}

@import "bootstrap";
```

It all depends on what other customizations you have.

https://codeply.com/go/3zTbKtczVd

---

Also see: [How to extend/modify (customize) Bootstrap 4 with SASS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776055/how-to-extend-modify-customize-bootstrap-4-with-sass)