# How to override Bootstraps "btn-primary" active background-color using SASS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I am using bootstrap 4 with SCSS and have troubles to find the variable which is responsible for the background of an "btn-primary" element which is active.

Of course I could just override the css file like that after the compiling process.

```
.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active{
  background-color:red;
}
```

But this is a bit hacky. I would like to undestand how bootstrap is generating this particular color? I am pretty sure I am missing something.

Please see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/10169/) and click on the test button to see what I mean.

**Solved:** The color is stored within $primary (Thank you ReSedano)

Just do a

```
$primary: #ff00ff;
```

before you load bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can understand **How to override boostrap4 using scss**: [How to extend/modify (customize) Bootstrap 4 with SASS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776055/how-to-extend-modify-customize-bootstrap-4-with-sass).

In your case you have to override the map `$theme-colors`:

```
$theme-colors: (
  "primary": #ff0000 // <= put here your color
);
```

To understand *"how bootstrap is generating this particular color?"* in `_buttons.scss` file you can find the function:

```
@each $color, $value in $theme-colors {
  .btn-#{$color} {
    @include button-variant($value, $value);
  }
}
```

So to change colors, Bootstrap loop the map call `$theme-colors` that you find in `_variable.scss` file.

```
$theme-colors: () !default;

$theme-colors: map-merge(
  (
    "primary":    $primary,
    "secondary":  $secondary,
    "success":    $success,
    "info":       $info,
    "warning":    $warning,
    "danger":     $danger,
    "light":      $light,
    "dark":       $dark
  ),
  $theme-colors
);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple error . bootstrasp.css  after style.css if yes can you move bootstrap.css  before style.css

like

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- custom CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

use css in style.css

```
.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled) {
background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Theme  colors is defined in [_variables.scss](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_variables.scss)

Buttons is generated in [_buttons.scss](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_buttons.scss) and uses [button-variant() mixin](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/mixins/_buttons.scss)

```
// _variables.scss
$theme-colors: map-merge(
  (
    "primary":    $primary,
    "secondary":  $secondary,
    "success":    $success,
    "info":       $info,
    "warning":    $warning,
    "danger":     $danger,
    "light":      $light,
    "dark":       $dark
  ),
  $theme-colors
);

// _buttons.scss
@each $color, $value in $theme-colors {
  .btn-#{$color} {
    @include button-variant($value, $value);
  }
}
```