# scss bootstrap 4 overwrite map

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4

I'm trying my hand at scss using Bootstrap 4 and I don't know how to overwrite variable (using map) correclty

*custom.scss*

```
// Your variable overrides
$primary: rgb(40, 167, 36);

$spacer: 1;
$spacers: (
  0: 0,
  1: ($spacer * .2),
  2: ($spacer * 3),
  3: $spacer,
  4: ($spacer * 8),
  5: ($spacer * 12),
  6: ($spacer * 50)
);


// Bootstrap and its default variables
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Primary color overwrite works fine but the spacers don't.

As is it now it seems like all the value are equal to 0, whenever I add a class like "mt-5" it doesn't change anything.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: This post can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776055/how-to-extend-modify-customize-bootstrap-4-with-sass

Comment: I did as it says but still not working, I added 
`@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";`
`@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";`
to the top but now even $primary overwrite doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to add spacers to the map. The issue is that the `spacer` has no units. Use `px` or `rem` to define the `spacer` unit...

```
$spacer: 1rem;
$spacers: (
  0: 0,
  1: ($spacer * .2),
  2: ($spacer * 3),
  3: $spacer,
  4: ($spacer * 8),
  5: ($spacer * 12),
  6: ($spacer * 50)
);
```

https://codeply.com/go/TY8XqnvzO9