# Cannot override Bootstrap 5 utilities

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-5

My SCSS structure:

main.scss:

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import 'theme/variables';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import 'theme/theme';
```

theme.scss:

```
...
@import "utilities"
```

utilities.scss:

```
$utilities: (
  "overflow": (
    responsive: true,
    property: overflow,
    values: visible hidden scroll auto,
  ),
);
```

The above is basically an example from the documentation. This was supposed to add new overflow utilities classes. However, nothing was added. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like I have to keep those in `variables.scss`. I wonder if there is a way to keep it in `theme.scss`.

Comment: I had a similar problem in bs4, with variable scope overriding, not sure if this will be of any use to you, as i've not played with the bs5 alpha yet... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54009129/overriding-default-border-radius-lg-variable-in-theming-bootstrap-4

Comment: Try importing `theme.scss` before `variables.scss`! That could work.

Answer (score 2):

Move the `@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"` **after** the declaration of the additional utilities.

**More details**

At the time of writing this answer (May 2021), for **Bootstrap v5.0.0-beta3**, the following solution should work, as stated in the official docs:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/api/#changing-utilities

> Override existing utilities by using the same key.

```
$utilities: (
  "overflow": (
    responsive: true,
    property: overflow,
    values: visible hidden scroll auto,
  ),
);

@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Please note that:

- the `@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"` should go **after** the declaration of the additional utilities.

**Live demo**: https://www.codeply.com/p/oX8ELBwVgB

Answer (score -1):

Don't you have to add overrides before `@import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities";`

```
// Your utilities overrides
$utilities: (
    "text-decoration": (
        property: text-decoration,
        class: td,
        state: hover,
        values: none underline line-through overline,
    ),
);

@import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities";
```