# Bootstrap Theming Not Replacing

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

Hey I have a problem here which I have no idea what is going on. I am trying to change the colors from bootstrap using SCSS however it is not working whenever i run `npm run serve` in my Vue project.

These are in my files

**custom_bootstrap.scss**

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "_config.scss";

$primary: $primary-color-red;

@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

**_config.scss**

```
//Color Palette
$primary-color-red: #C00800; 
$primary-text: #666666;
$main-text: #8F8F8F;

//Font Size
$main-fontsize: 15px;
```

**main.scss**

```
@import 'custom_bootstrap';

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

**main.js**

```
...
import 'bootstrap';
import './assets/styles/main.scss';
...
```

As you can see I am trying to change the color of `$primary` to a value from `_config.scss`. However when I ran `npm run serve` the color remains the default blue. Anyone able to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import the bootstrap and it's default variables after overriding it.

More about it here, https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/reference/theming

**custom_bootstrap.scss**

```
@import "_config.scss";

$primary: $primary-color-red;

@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Try that, and see if it works

Comment: A quick note: `node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap` also imports `functions`, `mixins` and `variables`, so they don't need to be explicitly imported.

Comment: Thank you that worked however I was so confused I was following this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776055/how-to-extend-modify-customize-bootstrap-4-with-sass) it mentioned to import the variables first...