# Add new utilities with Bootstrap 5

Tags: sass, utilities, bootstrap-5

Following the B5 new documentation, this is how you are supposed to add new utilities with the new utilities API. I have not been the get the new output though.

**exemple:**

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities";

$utilities: map-merge(
  $utilities,
  (
    "cursor": (
      property: cursor,
      class: cursor
      responsive: true,
      values: auto pointer grab,
    )
  )
);
```

**my file:**

```
@import "bootstrap.scss";
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities";

$utilities: map-merge(
  $utilities,
  (
    "button-rounded": (
      property: border-radius,
      class: button-rounded,
      values: (
        null: 20px,
      ),
    ),
  )
);
```

- I need to import bootstrap.scss because $utilities is undefined otherwise
- the goal is to add a new property to make the button rounded.simple example to test out the new API. not working though
- I am using the https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-npm-starter to compile the scss files:
  the **src** is starter.scss and the output is starter.css

I cannot find the new property **button-rounded**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When [making Bootstrap SASS customizations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776055/how-to-extend-modify-customize-bootstrap-4-with-sass/49070142#49070142), the `@import "bootstrap"` should go *after* the changes. Also, the utilities file requires the variables file, and the variables file requires the functions file, so you must import all 3 before the change...

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities";

$utilities: map-merge(
  $utilities,
  (
    "button-rounded": (
      property: border-radius,
      class: button-rounded,
      values: (
        null: 20px,
      ),
    ),
  )
);

@import "bootstrap";
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/2dHkmMD376)

Since Bootstrap 5 is currently beta, I've submitted an [issue report](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/32557) for this.

Comment: I just found this out myself the hard way that the main bootstrap import needs to come after. It would be nice if the docs mentioned that. And since they are using `@import` instead of `@use` we are basically importing those 3 files `functions`, `variables`, and `utilities` twice bc the main `@import "bootstrap"` also imports those 3 files which unnecessarily increases the size of the css. Is this the way they intended the utilities API to be used?  Per SASS "Each stylesheet is executed and its CSS emitted every time it’s @imported, which increases compilation time and produces bloated output"

Comment: I have been wondering the same thing. All the answers I can find say import bootstrap after but like you said it should be unnecessary to reimport everything again.

Comment: That's how SASS works.... it's not a bootstrap thing

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap 5.0.1, somehow no luck with `map-merge($utilities ...)`

but bootstrap has one more extension point: by overriding every $var default value

following will merge inside `@import '~bootstrap/scss/utilities';`

```css
$utilities: (
  'event-type': (
    property: background-color,
    class: 'event-type', // <- somehow this required
    values: (
      commit: #BADA55,
      issue: #C0FFEE,
    ),
  ),
);

@import '~bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/variables';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/mixins';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/utilities';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/utilities/api';
```

Comment: This is the only thing I have found that works without reimporting all of bootstrap thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As of Bootstrap 5.0.1 this would be more appropriate:

```js
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities";
@import "bootstrap/scss/helpers";
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities/api";

$utilities: map-merge(
  $utilities,
  (
    "button-rounded": (
      property: border-radius,
      class: button-rounded,
      values: (
        null: 20px,
      ),
    ),
  )
);
```

Importing "bootstrap" at the end is not required anymore.

Answer (score 1):

For bootstrap 5.1.3 from [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/customize/color/#generating-utilities)

Don't forget `@import "bootstrap/scss/maps";` as it's needed by utilities.

```js
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "bootstrap/scss/maps";
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities";

$utilities: map-merge(
  $utilities,
  (
    "button-rounded": (
      property: border-radius,
      class: button-rounded,
      values: (
        null: 20px,
      ),
    ),
  )
);

@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities/api";
```

Comment: I needed to import all 5 of those to access the $utilities variable. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since **Bootstrap 5.2. update** you need to proceed a little different. There is new `maps` file added.

If you are working with SCSS and you would like to modify colors you should add  maps to your SCSS file.

```
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/maps"; // MAPS FILE - SINCE 5.2
```

and then:

```
$custom-colors: (
        "white": $white, // your colours
);
$theme-colors: map-merge($theme-colors, $custom-colors);
$theme-colors-rgb: map-loop($theme-colors, to-rgb, "$value");
$utilities-colors: map-merge($utilities-colors, $theme-colors-rgb);
$utilities-text-colors: map-loop($utilities-colors, rgba-css-var, "$key", "text");
$utilities-bg-colors: map-loop($utilities-colors, rgba-css-var, "$key", "bg");
```

and finally:

```
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities";
```

and the rest.

Comment: How do you add a text color without having to add it to themecolors?