# How to Customize Bootstrap 5 Font Size for fs-* class in SASS variables

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-5

how to change Bootstrap 5 `fs-*` class in *sass*? because In the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/text/#variables) only shows how to modify  `h-*` class such as `h5-font-size`, but not the `fs-*` class.

Comment: Please accept the answer so others know the question is solved!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would modify the "font-size" utility using the [Utilities API](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/api/#modify-utilities). Merge the new values with the existing $font-sizes map...

```
@import "functions";
@import "variables";
@import "utilities";

$font-sizes: (
  1: 12rem,
  2: 10rem,
  3: 7rem,
  4: 5rem,
  5: 3rem,
  6: 2rem,
);

$utilities: map-merge(
  $utilities,
  (
    "font-size": map-merge(
      map-get($utilities, "font-size"),
      (
        values: $font-sizes,
      ),
    ),
  )
);

@import "bootstrap";
```

[SASS Demo](https://www.codeply.com/p/BNnGzvQBha)

---

Related: [Add new utilities with Bootstrap 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65376233/add-new-utilities-with-bootstrap-5/65380422#65380422)