# how to modify bootstrap 5's font sizes to add fs-7 class

Tags: bootstrap-5

I'm trying to add the "fs-7" css class to bootstrap5.

Following this guide: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/api/#modify-utilities

I came up with this custom scss file:

```
@import '../../../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';


$h7-font-size: $font-size-base * 0.75; // $font-size-base is defined in _variables.scss


$utilities: map-merge(
        $utilities,
        (
            "font-size": map-merge(
                    map-get($utilities, "font-size"),
                    (
                        values: map-merge(
                                map-get(map-get($utilities, "font-size"), "values"),
                                (7: $h7-font-size),
                        ),
                    ),
            ),
        )
);
```

But when I call css class "fs-7" in my code, it's not recognized.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Customize Bootstrap 5 Font Size for fs-\* class in SASS variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68126285/how-to-customize-bootstrap-5-font-size-for-fs-class-in-sass-variables)

Answer (score 2):

Ok found it. Turns out you need to define the variable $utilities BEFORE you call the bootstrap files.

So this worked:

```
@import "../../../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../../../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../../../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities";



$h7-font-size: $font-size-base * 0.75;


$utilities: map-merge(
        $utilities,
        (
            "font-size": map-merge(
                    map-get($utilities, "font-size"),
                    (
                        values: map-merge(
                                map-get(map-get($utilities, "font-size"), "values"),
                                (7: $h7-font-size),
                        ),
                    ),
            ),
        )
);

@import '../../../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

Comment: That works but you can shorten the code a lot. In between your imports, you could do something like this: `$custom-font-sizes: (7: $font-size-base * 0.75); $font-sizes: map-merge($font-sizes, $custom-font-sizes);`

Answer (score 0):

You will find the complete list of Bootstrap’s variables in
bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss

Copy and paste variable and modify their values.

```
$font-sizes: (
  1: 2.25rem,
  2: 1.875rem,
  3: 1.5625rem,
  4: 1.25rem,
  5: 1.125rem,
  6: 1.025rem,
  7: 5rem,
);
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, the **how** is important, but a great part of the quality level of the site comes from the fact that people go to great lengths to explain the **why**. While a _code-only_ answer get the person who asked the question past whatever hurdle they might be facing, it doesn't do them or future visitors much good in the long run. See [Is there any benefit in code-only answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/183937)

Answer (score 0):

When I had a similar problem, what I did was download the bootstrap-utilities.css file from bootstrap's official website and place it in the css subfolder of my project. Apparently, I had been using utilities that could not be recognized.

Font size is included in those utilities.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference:

```
// global.scss
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";

@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";

$font-sizes: (
    1: $h1-font-size,
    2: $h2-font-size,
    3: $h3-font-size,
    4: $h4-font-size,
    5: $h5-font-size,
    6: $h6-font-size,
    7: 12rem, // adds fs-7
    n1: 0.25rem, // adds fs-n1
);

@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

For the why, please refer to: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/sass/