# Override Bootstrap class with scss, but only when the Bootstrap class is nested under a custom class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'd like to customize a Bootstrap class (`btn`, in the following example), but only when it's nested under my own class (`banner-message`, in the following example):

```
<div class="banner-message">
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

This is the SCSS ([live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dheu9k5z/)):

```
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  
  btn {
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: orange;
  }
}
```

I tried following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776055/how-to-extend-modify-customize-bootstrap-4-with-sass/49070142#49070142), and enclose my classes' file with the following, but it didn't work:

```
@import "bootstrap/btn";

... my classes' definitions

@import "bootstrap";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go...

You missed a dot before the `btn` class.

**HTML:**

```
<div class='banner-message'>
    <button class='btn btn-primary'>Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

**SCSS:**

```
body {
    background: #20262E;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}
  
.banner-message {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
    
    .btn {
      border-radius: 8px;
      color: orange;
    }
}
```

See the forked JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/go4en0s5/).

Comment: Thanks, though I'm looking for an scss overriding solution, similar to the answer I linked to. Using `!important` all over the place is not a good practice here, I'm certain we can do better.

Comment: Ah, you're right :) It didn't occur to me that the linked question is relevant to css modules, and so isn't relevant to my question, thanks.