# Bootstrap. How to change $spacer variable?

Tags: html, css, sass, bootstrap-5

I want to change $spacer variable to make all margins bigger, but it just don't work.
I'm trying to change it through SASS:

```
@import url(../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss);
@import url(../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss);
@import url(../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_utilities);

$spacer: 15rem;

@import url(../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss);

:root {
  --bs-body-font-family: 'Inter', Arial;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5.93rem;
  line-height: 121%;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  line-height: 212%;
}

h3 { 
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 120%;
}
```

I tried to place this `$spacer: 15rem` where it should be. After import `function.scss` and before `bootstrap.scss`.

Here is output css file:

```css
@import url(../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss);
@import url(../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss);
@import url(../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_utilities);
@import url(../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss);
:root {
  --bs-body-font-family: 'Inter', Arial;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5.93rem;
  line-height: 121%;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  line-height: 212%;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 120%;
}
```

I found the first problem, I used `@import url(./././././.)`, but now I use `@import "././././"` and css output now normal. But it's still don't change margins.

Comment: Are you certain you've rebuild the CSS and aren't getting a cached version? Have you looked at the final rendered CSS to see what it contains?

Comment: @ceejayoz I added result css after compiling scss file

Comment: If you changed the @imports as you stated you should not see the `@import url(...` in the output. It should only show the CSS. Something's wrong with how your compiling the SASS, and if we can't reproduce it we can't help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extend/modify (customize) Bootstrap with SASS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776055/how-to-extend-modify-customize-bootstrap-with-sass)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [stated in the Bootstrap 5 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/sass/#variable-defaults),

> Variable overrides must come after our functions are imported, but before the rest of the imports.

So changing the `$spacer` value should be simply:

```
// required
@import "functions";

// default variable overrides
$spacer: 5rem;

// individual imports or bootstrap entirely
@import "bootstrap";
```

[SASS demo](https://codeply.com/p/pjmV67jI4T)

Comment: I edited scss how you wrote, but margins still the same... You can see result css file at my question.