# Bootstrap CSS variables not being replaced

Tags: php, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, bootstrap-5

I am developing some custom styles in Laravel and overriding the default bootstrap color variables.

This is inside my **app.scss**

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss";

$primary: #625BF6;
$danger: #ff4136;

.btn-primary {
    --bs-btn-bg: $primary;
    --bs-btn-hover-bg: #6b64f5;
    --bs-btn-active-bg: #534bf3;
}
```

I have also made the changes in **webpack.mix.js** to use sass as the compiler

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/css/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

However, even after running **npm watch** or **npm run dev**, the variable $primary is not being substituted.

[image]

Why would this happen?

EDIT: I don't think its about bootstrap anymore or the order of variable. The variable is simply not being substituted.

Comment: AFAIK Bootstrap variables have to be replaced before the framework import. I personnaly put it in a _variables.scss file, and import it first

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extend/modify (customize) Bootstrap with SASS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776055/how-to-extend-modify-customize-bootstrap-with-sass)

Comment: @OMiShah think this is not even about bootstrap anymore. The variable $primary is not being replaced in my css. it is just showing up as is.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [breaking change](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/css-vars) in a recent SCSS version. The reason is `$primary` is actually a valid value for a CSS variable so it is no longer automatically replaced (in case that's what you wanted to input). To get the actual SCSS variable to be used you need to use interpolation:

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss";

$primary: #625BF6;
$danger: #ff4136;

.btn-primary {
    --bs-btn-bg: #{$primary};
    --bs-btn-hover-bg: #6b64f5;
    --bs-btn-active-bg: #534bf3;
}
```

Comment: Using interpolation didn't replace it either. I've given the answer to this question myself in one of the below answers. sass does not support css variables being set from sass variables. Using the $primary value in a non variable css property works fine.

Comment: @YD8877 that is factually incorrect. I had the exact same issue and interpolation fixed it for me. SCSS definately supports setting CSS variables using SCSS variables in this way

Answer (score 0):

Try to define the variable and then import it.

```
// Define variables
$primary: #625BF6;
$danger: #ff4136;

// Import styles
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss";

.btn-primary {
    --bs-btn-bg: $primary;
    --bs-btn-hover-bg: #6b64f5;
    --bs-btn-active-bg: #534bf3;
}
```

Then `npm watch` or `npm run dev`

Comment: I think this is not even about bootstrap anymore. The variable $primary is not being replaced in my css. it is just showing up as is.

Answer (score 0):

The sass value is getting replaced for a regular property but not for css variables

```
$primary:   #625BF6;
$danger:    #ff4136;

@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

.btn-primary {
    background-color:$primary;
    --bs-btn-bg: $primary;
    --bs-btn-hover-bg: #6b64f5;
    --bs-btn-active-bg: #534bf3;
}
```

[image]

So, it looks like sass does not support css variables being set from sass variables.